# Continuous Approximation of Lp function on $\mathbf{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, lp-spaces, approximation-theory

**I would like to show the following statement:**

For each $g\in L_1(\mathbf{R}^n,m)$ and each
$\epsilon>0$, there exists a continuous function $f:\mathbf{R}^n\to\mathbf{R}$ such
that
$$
\int |f-g|\,dm <\epsilon.
$$
**I have proven the following statement which was told to be useful:**

For each bounded Lebesgue measurable $A\subset\mathbf{R}^n$ and each $\epsilon>0$,
there exists a continuous function $f_A:\mathbf{R}^n \to [0,1]$ with compact support such that
$$
\int |f_A-\chi_A|\,dm <\epsilon.
$$

**Attempted Proof for the first statement:**
Let $g \in L_1(\mathbf{R}^n, m)$, $\epsilon > 0$ be given. In particular, there exists some $k \in \mathbf{R}$ such that
$$
g = g|_{[-k, k]^n} + g|_{\mathbf{R}^n - [-k, k]^n},
$$
and that
$$
\int_{\mathbf{R}^n - [-k, k]^p} |g| \, dm < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.
$$
Now note that there exists simple functions
$$
s(x)= \sum_{i = 1} ^m a_i \chi_{A_i}(x)
$$
such that $\| g|_{[-k, k]^p} - s \|_{L_1} < \epsilon/2$ with $A_i$ bounded. Now note that by the statement proven, for all $i$, there exists continuous functions $f_{A_i}: \mathbf{R}^n \to [0, 1]$ such that
$$
\int |f_{A_i} - \chi_{A_i}| \, dm < \epsilon.
$$
Therefore, we have
\begin{align*}
    \int |g - \sum_{i = 1} ^m a_i f_{A_i}| \, dm &= \int | g|_{[-k, k]^n} - \sum_{i = 1} ^m a_i f_{A_i}| \, dm + \int |g|_{\mathbf{R}^n - [-k, k]^n}| \, dm \\
    &\leq | g|_{[-k, k]^n} - \sum_{i = 1} ^m a_i \chi_{A_i}| \, dm + \int |\sum_{i = 1} ^m a_i f_{A_i} - \sum_{i = 1}^m a_i \chi_{A_i}| \, dm + \int |g|_{\mathbf{R}^n - [-k, k]^n}| \\
    &< \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \sum_{i = 1} ^m |a_i| \int |f_{A_i} - \chi_{A_i}| \, dm + \frac{\epsilon}{2} \\
    &< \epsilon + \sum_{i = 1} ^m |a_i| \epsilon \\
    &= \epsilon(1 + \sum_{i = 1} ^m |a_i|).
\end{align*}
***Since $\epsilon > 0$ is arbitrary, we are done.***

**My Doubts:** I think the last sentence where we reached the conclusion is faulty. In particular, I think our $a_i$ in the last part of the inequality actually depends on $\epsilon > 0$. Therefore, it is not very clear how this gives the desired result. However, I am not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the simple function $f$ is fixed, you can choose $f_{A_i}$ such that
$$
\lvert a_i\rvert \int |f_{A_i} - \chi_{A_i}| \, dm < \epsilon/m.
$$

Alternatively, you can define $g_N(x)=g(x)\mathbf{1}_{\lvert g(x)\rvert\leqslant N}$, take $N$ such that $\lVert g-g_N\rVert_1<\varepsilon/2$ and then use the statement with $f_A=g_N$.